# Use result of WITH clause to filter WHERE ... IN columnName

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, where-clause

I want to use the result of a WITH clause to filter a query like below:

```
WITH Max_Dates AS (
    SELECT MAX(created_date) AS maxdate
    FROM transactions
    GROUP BY DATE (created_date)
)
SELECT *
FROM transactions
WHERE created_date IN Max_Dates -- can I somehow reference column maxdate as a list here?
```

The syntax is incorrect. I know I can use the content of the WITH clause as a subquery in the WHERE below to get the result I want, but I want to know specifically if the WITH result can be used.

My question is, is there a general syntax for using a column from a WITH clause to filter as a list in a WHERE ... IN {list}?

As per [this blog](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-with-clause/) it seems it should be possible to use `WHERE created_at IN Max_Dates.maxdate`, but I'm using MySQL 8.0.29 and it doesn't like that syntax - Error: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Max_Dates.maxdate' at line 8")

Comment: What are you really trying to do? What is the datatype of `created_date`? It looks like you are trying to get most recently created transaction, is that correct? Or are you trying to get most recently created transactions *for each day*? In either case, I would expect a transaction identifier in the cte to make sure the date you are comparing to actually belongs to the same transaction, rather than just some more-or-less 'random' date

Comment: @HoneyBadger yup, get the most recent transaction for each day. The transaction I'm getting in Max_dates exactly matches a transaction time in the transactions table (since the cte is built from transactions and keeps the DATETIME value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH Max_Dates AS 
(
  SELECT MAX(created_date) AS maxdate
  FROM transactions
  GROUP BY DATE (created_date)
)
SELECT *
FROM transactions
WHERE created_date IN (select maxdate from Max_Dates)
```

The CTE (Common Table Expression) `Max_Dates` is a resultset that potentially has multiple columns, so you must specify the specific column from `Max_Dates` that should be used to build the list of values for the `IN` expression.

Comment: Thanks! This is the syntax I was looking for. Didn't really think about selecting the column individually. In terms of best practices, is it better to use a subquery to filter in the WHERE clause as opposed to the cte in this scenario?